# Simulate Session Timeout/Expiration in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, session, timeout, developer-console, expired-sessions

I have a piece of code I need to test for a case where the user is detected via cookies, but the session has timed out. To save myself from waiting around, is there a way I can modify the session in dev tools to simulate a timeout?

I know you can completely clear a session via the application tab (shown below) but this doesn't have the desired effect for me. Wondering if there is something else hidden in dev tools that I am not aware of yet. Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of Application tab in dev tools with emphasis on session storage]

Answer (score 1):

You can edit expiration time in Cookies and set an expired time there.

[image]

Comment: this does not work for me. i dont have option to edit content rather it edits the title